# Prove that the prime numbers set can be defined in a model

Tags: logic, second-order-logic

Given first order language, $L = <0, S, +, \cdot, = >$, $0$ is the number zero, $S$ is the successor function, and a model $M$ with the domain $\mathbb{N}$, I need to prove that the prime numbers set can be defined in $M$ using $L$

I came up with the following formula:
$$\varphi(x)=\exists_U(\neg U(S(0))\wedge\forall_x[U(x)\leftrightarrow\forall_y\forall_z((y\cdot z = x)\rightarrow([(y = x) \wedge (z= S(0))] \vee [(y=S(0)) \wedge (z = x)]))]) \wedge U(x)$$
(U(n) means $x\in U$)

The formula says there is a subset $U$, $1\notin U$, such that for every $x$, $x\in U$, if and only if the only numbers whose product equals $x$ are $x$ and $1$, and the last part says that the free variable $x$ is an element of the subset $U$ (and thus a prime number)

But this formula seems overcomplicated, is there a simpler, clearer formula to define prime numbers?

Comment: "Definable" usually means "definable in first-order logic," but you've used a second-order formula (and the second-order logic tag). Is that what you intended?

Comment: I know it's usually in first order but I couldn't find a formula for prime numbers set in first order logic, so I did it with second-order

Comment: Instead of first saying that $U$ consists of the numbers that have some long property and then saying that $x$ is in $U$, you could just say that $x$ has that long property.